# How to cancel notifications with a notification priority higher than low with Notification Listener in Android 5.0 - 6.0?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, push-notification, notification-listener

I created a service using NotificationListenerService, and in onNotificationPosted I just run a simple if:

```
if (sbn.isClearable && sbn.packageName == myPackageName) {
   this.cancelNotification(sbn.key)
}
```

Now, this code works flawlessly from android 7.0 and above, but it doesn't work with 5.0 and 6.0. 
To be more precise, it works on 5.0 and 6.0 only with notifications with a priority set to `minimum`, but with other priority levels it always start a vibration, sounds or a heads up, depending of the level.

How can I snooze the incoming notifications?

I'm creating this project in Kotlin, so answers in this language will be more appreciated, but I appreciate Java as well.

Comment: Do you mean on Android 5/6 the new notification (priority minimum) triggers the vibration/sound and does not cancel the previous notification? So you want to replace a notification? What about updating it? Please describe more scenarii, it'll help I'm sure

Comment: @shkschneider no I just want to prevent notifications from low priority to above to trigger heads up, sounds and vibrations when they come.
User case, I want to block Facebook notifications but not Whatsapp: with low priority notifications it works good, but not with higher priority. I know that it may sounds foolish ("why not just disable notifications from settings?"), but that's what I need.

Comment: Did you manage to achieve what you were working on? I face the same problem.

Comment: Hi, @EliaCrocetta if you managed to find the solution for this please help me. I am facing the same issue